# Dumping a INT32 array into a .bin file

Tags: c

I have the array defined as below

```
INT32 LUT_OffsetValues[6][12] = {
0,180,360,540,720,900,1080,1260,1440,1620,1800,1980,
2160,2340,2520,2700,2880,3060,3240,3420,3600,3780,3960,4140,
4320,4500,4680,4860,5040,5220,5400,5580,5760,5940,6120,6300,
6480,6660,6840,7020,7200,7380,7560,7740,7920,8100,8280,8460,
8640,8820,9000,9180,9360,9540,9720,9900,10080,10260,10440,10620,
10800,10980,11160,11340,11520,11700,11880,12060,12240,12420,12600,12780
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
 int var_row_index = 4 ;
int var_column_index = 5 ;
int computed_val = 0 ;
FILE *fp = NULL ;

fp = fopen("./LUT_Offset.bin","wb");
if(NULL != fp)
{
    fwrite(LUT_OffsetValues,sizeof(INT32),72,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

printf("Size of Array:%d\n",sizeof(LUT_OffsetValues));
//computed_val  =  LUT_OffsetValues[var_row_index][var_column_index];
return 0;
}
```

Above is the code snippet with which I have generated the .bin file. Is that the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the right way if you plan to transfer the file to a different machine and read it as you haven't considered the [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Let's say the file is:

1. Written in little endian machine but read in big endian machine
2. Written in big endian machine but read in little endian machine

It won't work for none of the cases above.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the order of the bytes signaled by askinoor, that way is not generic because the reader have to now it is an `INT32[6][12]` when it read it

Why the useless variables `var_row_index` etc in your program ?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, when serializing data in and out of the CPU it is preferable to force network byte order. This can be done easily using functions like `htonl()`, which should be available on most platforms (and compile down to nothing on big endian machines).

Here's the doc from Linux:
https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl

Also, it's not good practice to explicitly code sizes and types into your program.
Use `sizeof(array[0][0])` to get the size of the element type of `array`, then iterate over it and use `htonl()` to write each element to the file.